# How to solve the following error in Wpf System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox'.'

Tags: c#

I have created a wpf(.net framework) application  for a user to login but I keep on getting this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox'.'

This is my code:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string mainconn = "Data Source=VCPTCR4PC19\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TASK2;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
    conn.Open();

    string cmds = $" Select * from USERS (@USERS_NAME, @USERS_PASSWORD ) ";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmds, conn);
    command.Parameters.Add("@USERS_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= txtUsername.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@USERS_PASSWORD", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = HashCode.PassHash(password.Password);
     

    SqlDataAdapter sqlData = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From USERS Where USER_NAME = '" + txtUsername + "'and PASSWORD'" + password + "'", conn);
     
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    sqlData.Fill(dataTable);
    if (dataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")                
    {
        this.Hide();
        Modules modules = new Modules();
        modules.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invaild user name or password enterd");
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPC1S.png)

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You're missing the `=` after `PASSWORD`. There's more wrong with it, but once you're using parameters for the second query, you can step through it and see the other mistakes. VTC as a typo.